# Git cannot push to master

Tags: git, github

Ive been working on my project and created a branch (newBranch). Now that newBranch is 13 commits ahead and 1 commit behind remote master (cause I edited readME online on github).

I read bunch of questions here, and somehow I think I made it worse.
Now when I push to master I get

```
 = [up to date]      master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
Everything up-to-date
```

But when I go on my github it is saying newBranch is 14 commit ahead of master. What's going on?? How do I fix it, I just want master branch to be same as my newBranch

Comment: Explain what relationship you want to have between `newBranch` and `master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either merge `newBranch` into `master`, or you can try rebasing `master` on `newBranch`.  Since you are a beginner, you might find the merge option to be the easiest for you:

```
git checkout master   # switch to the master branch
git merge newBranch   # merge newBranch into master
```

Then you can push the updated `master` out to GitHub:

```
git push origin master
```

Keep in mind there might be merge conflicts which you will have to resolve manually (look for markers like `<<<` and `===`).

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly. but what exactly caused the problem I had? Why couldnt I push to master even though I already got the updated readme, and why was it saying master was up to date?

Comment: This would require a long answer.  As to the second part, when Git tells you that you are behind or ahead a branch, it is using your _local_ tracking branch as a reference, not the actual branch which exists in GitHub.  This is a head fake, and you might conclude that you should be able to pull/push when in fact you cannot.  So really `master` may not have been up to date.

Comment: oh so it must be cause I messed up the ref when I was playing around. So if I were to somehow corrected my ref it would have worked too?

Comment: Actually it looks like nothing was wrong with your `master` branch at all.  It was just that `newBranch` on the remote was behind your local work.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want master branch to be same as my newBranch.

Go to Github.com, switch to newBranch, `New Pull Request`, then merge your branches.